# A component is changing a controlled input of type text to be uncontrolled error in react

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-component, react-functional-component

I am creating a react application in which I have two components say Parent and Child but one thing to note that **I am using stateless components(functional component) and hooks** in entire application.

//Parent.jsx

```
 import React, { useState } from "react";

    function Parent() {
    const [firstName, setFirstName] = useState("");
    const handleChange = event => {setFirstName(event.value);}
...
Rest Code
...
}
```

//Child.jsx

```
    function Child(props) {
          <label htmlFor="validationCustom01">First Name</label>
                    <input
                      type="text"
                      className="form-control"
                      placeholder="enter first name"
                      value={props.firstName || ""}
                      onChange={props.handleChange}
                      required
                    />
    ...
Rest Code
...
    }
```

The page renders perfectly but as soon as write in textbox it gives following error

***A component is changing a controlled input of type text to be uncontrolled. Input elements should not switch from controlled to uncontrolled (or vice versa).***

I tried all possible solutions but this is not working. However similar functionality works perfectly in class component but not in functional component. Any idea?

Comment: are you sure that happens to `<input placeholder="enter first name" ...>`? this switch happens once your `value` prop becomes `undefined` or `null`. But your code has clear `|| ""` that will work in such a case.

Comment: yup it is happening, that's why I mentioned I tried all possible answers from google

Comment: can you make live sandbox?